# XOR Encryption algorithm unable to handle input greater than 127 chars in length

Tags: c++, qt

I have an identical encryption method on my client and my server:

```
QByteArray Server::encrypt(QString input){
    std::string original = input.toStdString();
    std::string encrypted = "";

    std::string key = "key";

    for (unsigned int temp = 0; temp < original.size(); temp++){
        encrypted += original[temp] ^ ((atoi(key.c_str()) + temp) + 2) % 253;
    }

    QByteArray byteArray(encrypted.c_str(), encrypted.length());
    return byteArray;
}
```

And I'm passing a `QString` with a length of 143 characters into the function. When I pass a `QByteArray` containing the encrypted text to my decrypt function (which simply reverses this XOR encryption) it will correctly decrypt the first 126 characters, but the remainder of the string will be incorrectly decrypted. If I look at the encrypted string, all of the characters after the 126th are `?` instead of random characters as I would expect.

I'm not sure what's causing this. A `QByteArray` is an array of bytes, so the maximum value that one element can have is limited to the size of a byte, however I'm not sure why the *number of elements* seems to be limited to the size of a byte. Especially considering that `QByteArray::size()` returns an int.

When I debug the program and look at the contents of the `QByteArray`, elements 0-125 are okay, but the rest of the elements (the 127th element at location 126) are negative numbers - for example, instead of seeing `91 '['` as the value at a location, I see `-79 / 177`.

How do I go about fixing this issue, so I can run this encryption with input of a length greater than 126?

Comment: Are you always passing the same QString? Do you get different results with different QStrings?

Comment: @mp_ I've tried passing multiple QStrings of lengths greater than 126, and each time the algorithm falls apart after the 126th element. The results are the same; correct decryption up to the 126th element, elements after the 126th in the encrypted string are question marks, etc. Everything works fine, as long as the input is less than 127 characters long. But I need it to be able to handle inputs >= 127 characters.

Comment: If the encryption algorithm produce the value `0` for a byte, the line `encrypted += original[temp] ^ ((atoi(key.c_str()) + temp) + 2) % 253;` won't do anything. Not only that, the line `QByteArray byteArray(encrypted.c_str(), encrypted.length());` will end up accessing out of bound memory.

Comment: @RSahu I've never had this problem and I don't think the problem is that I'm getting zero for an element (since it happens for every element after 126 instead of just one element), though I guess that's another issue that I need to address. I suppose I'll just add one to the value that the algorithm produces during encryption, and subtract it during decryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the solution that @R Sahu provided (it didn't quite work either but was a step in the right direction), I've managed to solve the problem. The reworked encryption method I've written is:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> encrypt(QString input){
    std::string original = input.toStdString();
    size_t size = original.size();
    std::vector<unsigned char> encrypted(size);

    std::string key = "key"; //integer in the actual implementation

    for (unsigned int temp = 0; temp < original.size(); temp++){
        encrypted[temp] = original[temp] ^ ((atoi(key.c_str()) + temp) + 2) % 253;
    }

    return encrypted;
}
```

Instead of dealing with QByteArrays, (which seem to have issues when dealing with unsigned values, despite the fact that they shouldn't) I simply return the unsigned char vector and **keep it in this form**. When I decrypt, I take an unsigned char vector instead of a QByteArray, and return a QString using this method to convert the unsigned chars into signed chars for display purposes:

```
std::string reinterpretedString(reinterpret_cast<char*>(unencryptVector.data())); //unsigned --> signed
QString output;
output = QString::fromStdString(reinterpretedString); //output is now decrypted and readable
```

And I use the `reinterpret_cast<char*>()` function whenever I have an unsigned char vector and I want to do something with it (unsigned char vectors are not common enough for functions to have overloaded implementations for them), such as store it in a char array in preparation for sending data through a socket.

Answer (score 1):

If the encryption algorithm produce the value `0` for a byte, the line

```
encrypted += original[temp] ^ ((atoi(key.c_str()) + temp) + 2) % 253;
```

won't do anything. Not only that, the line

```
QByteArray byteArray(encrypted.c_str(), encrypted.length());
```

will end up accessing out of bound memory.

Also, you have defined

```
    std::string key = "key";
```

and then you are using `atoi(key.c_str())`. That will always return `0`. Hope that's an oversight.

I suggest:

```
QByteArray Server::encrypt(QString input){
    std::string original = input.toStdString();
    size_t size = original.size();
    std::vector<unsigned char> encrypted(size);

    std::string key = "key";

    for (unsigned int temp = 0; temp < size; temp++){
        encrypted[temp] = original[temp] ^ ((atoi(key.c_str()) + temp) + 2) % 253;
    }

    QByteArray byteArray(encrypted.data(), size);
    return byteArray;
}
```

Comment: Regarding the key, I just censored the key. In the actual implementation, it's a number (so `atoi` won't return zero every time). It looks like this implementation will fix the problem associated with the algorithm producing `0` right?

Comment: @Lighthat yes, it should.